# How to change the font of a colorbar ticks parameter on the label?

Tags: fonts, colorbar

[image]I want to use a consistent font throughout my figure (Times New Roman). But I can't modify the font next to the tick label, can anyone tell me?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy 

px_orbital = pd.read_csv("data1.csv", header=None)
px_orbital.head()
x = px_orbital.iloc[0, 1:]
y = px_orbital.iloc[1:, 0]
px_values = px_orbital.iloc[1:, 1:]
px_values.head()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pxt_values = numpy.transpose(px_values)

CS = ax.contourf(y, x, pxt_values, cmap="coolwarm")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel('Time (min)', fontdict={'family' : 'Times New Roman', 'size':10})
plt.ylabel('Depth (m)', fontdict={'family' : 'Times New Roman', 'size':10})
plt.xticks(fontproperties = 'Times New Roman', size = 10)
plt.yticks(fontproperties = 'Times New Roman', size = 10)

cb = plt.colorbar(CS, orientation="vertical", pad=0.01)
cb.set_label(label='Temperature ($^{\circ}$C)', fontdict={'family' : 'Times New Roman', 'size':10})
cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)
plt.savefig('./2.jpg', dpi=300)
```